# Single Email Message isnot triggering

Tags: singleemailmessage

I have created following Template (Visualforce Page Template):GDPR_Subscriber_Notification

If I do send Test and verify Merge fields option,Its working as expected

```
 <messaging:emailTemplate subject="New Privacy Request -Transaction number" 
recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="GDPRRequestSubscriberStatus__c">
```

```
     Dear {!relatedTo.GDPRSubscriber__r.Name},<br/><br/>              

   T***** Id          :   {!relatedTo.GDPRRequest__r.Name}<br/>   
   P****** Id              :   {!relatedTo.GDPRRequest__r.PrimaryId__c}
   D******               :   {!relatedTo.DueDateEOD__c}<br/>       
   R*****          :   {!relatedTo.GDPRRequest__r.RequestType__c}<br/>       
   Created Date            :   {!relatedTo.GDPRRequest__r.CreatedDate}<br/><br/>    

  Regards,<br/>       
  test Team
```

In the code Level:

```
public static void sendingEmailToMultipleSubscriber(List<GDPRSubscriber__c>gdprSubscriberEmailList,string SubId){
    system.debug('gdprSubscriberEmailList@@@'+gdprSubscriberEmailList);
    system.debug('SubId@@'+SubId);
    List<string> toAddress = new List<string>();
    for(GDPRSubscriber__c gdprSub:gdprSubscriberEmailList){
        toAddress.add(gdprSub.Email__c);
    }
    system.debug('toAddress@@@@@@@'+toAddress);
    EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id,Subject, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName ='GDPR_Subscriber_Notification'];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
    mail.setSubject(et.subject);
    mail.setHTMLBody(et.Body);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(SubId);
    // mail.setWhatId(primaryAccount);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    allmsg.add(mail);
    system.debug('all MSG'+allmsg);
    try {
        Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Debug Log:

```
  gdprSubscriberEmailList@@@(GDPRSubscriber__c:{Name=EADP-CI, Email__c=test1@gmail.com, Alias__c=qa-eadp-ci, Portal_Access__c=true, Active__c=true, Id=a7V0m0000000lKBEAY})

all MSG(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[getBccAddresses=null;getCcAddresses=null;getCharset=null;getEntityAttachments=null;getFileAttachments=null;getHtmlBody=null;getInReplyTo=null;getOptOutPolicy=SEND;getOrgWideEmailAddressId=null;getPlainTextBody=null;getReferences=null;getTargetObjectId=a7T0m000000DT05EAG;getTemplateId=00X0m000000uhYxEAI;getTemplateName=GDPR Subscriber Notification;getToAddresses=(test1@gmail.com);getWhatId=null;isTreatBodiesAsTemplate=false;isTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient=true;isUserMail=false;])
```

trying to use the above templates in this mail message but single email message is not triggering.

[image]

test1@gmail.com => dummy address. [Added in Question]

Comment: Is the To Address `test1@gmail.com` valid?

Comment: I have added dummy email address for question purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got ressoved:

two things:

```
 Contact cnt = [select id, Email from Contact where email != null limit 1];
 mail.setWhatId(whatID);//object Id
 mail.setTargetObjectId(cnt.id);
```

Second things:

Need to allow activities on Object Level.Otherwise it shows below error:

```
SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, SaveAsActivity is not allowed with whatId that is not supported as a task whatId.:
```

Comment: This is a great reason why you should _never_ swallow exceptions into the debug log. If you didn't hide the exception, you'd know about this failure right away.